# How to close all overlays in flutter

Tags: flutter, overlay

I have built a screen that builds an overlay which contains a search bar widget.

Because I've built the overlay call in one class which then loads a separate widget class containing the search bar. I can't workout how to close the overlay from the active search bar class.

I have tried creating a close or dispose function but this only works when called from the parent class that initiated the overlay and not the child class containing the search widget.

Is there a close or kill all overlay function that I can use in this situation?

Or a way of calling the dispose / close overlay function that resides in the parent class from the child class when the search widget is running?

The only work-around I can think of is to rebuild the overlay and the search bar functionality into a single class which seems wrong.

Comment: the only way for removing the overlay is to call `OverlayEntry.remove()` method - you cannot  "close all the overlays" as `Route`s (like `MaterialPageRoute` for example) use overlays under the hood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code for Overlay you'll see this gem:

[image]

Do you see the highlighted part? Internally Flutter uses a private variable called "_entries" that has access to all overlays that are displayed at the moment.

However this is a private variable. So to answer your question, unless you keep a reference to all your overlay entries and then closing them manually, you cannot ask the system to do that for you.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and here is my solution. I call the close function prior to opening a new overlay:

```
// OVERLAYS
OverlayEntry? overlayWidget;

void closeOverlay() {
  if ( overlayWidget == null || overlayWidget?.mounted == false) return;
  overlayWidget?.remove();
  overlayWidget = null;
}

void overlayWidgetDialog(BuildContext context, {required Widget child}) {
  // avoid stacking
  closeOverlay();
  overlayWidget = OverlayEntry(
      // maintainState: true,
      // opaque: true,
      builder: (context) {
        return child;
      });

  Overlay.of(context)?.insert(overlayWidget!);
}
```

Comment: Update:  add the "overlayWidget = null;" or you'll get an error (after flutter updates).